# Why the same SOQL query in apex class in constructor and in apex test method returns different results?

Tags: soql, unit-test

In apex class (in constructor) this block of code:

```
        String xxx = 'data123'; // hardcoded
        xxx = xxx + '%';
        List<Interface__c> records = [SELECT Name FROM Interface__c where Name LIKE :xxx limit 50000];
        System.debug('record = ' +  records);
```

returns correct records. But in Apex class this returns only this:

```
records = ()
```

What may be the reason of this and how can I retrieve records in Apex class? Code for unit test method body looks like first code snippet.

Comment: You need to create your records. Test methods, unless marked with `seeAllData=true` (not recommended), they need you to create your test data. You start the test with  pretty much empty sObjects

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0 and later, **test methods don’t have access by default to pre-existing data in the organization, such as standard objects, custom objects, and custom settings data, and can only access data that they create**. However, objects that are used to manage your organization or metadata objects can still be accessed in your tests such as:

- User
- Profile
- Organization
- AsyncApexJob
- CronTrigger
- RecordType
- ApexClass
- ApexTrigger
- ApexComponent
- ApexPage

> Whenever possible, you should create test data for each test. You can
>   disable this restriction by annotating your test class or test method
>   with the IsTest(SeeAllData=true) annotation.

Read more here:- [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm)